# Make function generic with respect to pointers and references

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I have this C++ function:

```
class C { ... };

void do(const vector<C>& cs) {
   ...
   for (...) {
      cs[i].do_whatever();
   }
   ...
}
```

But `C` is expensive to copy so I might have something like this:

```
std::vector<C*> reorder_in_some_way(const std::vector<C>& cs) {
   ...
}

int main() {
   std::vector<C> cs = ...;

   std::vector<C*> reorderedCs = reorder_in_some_way(cs);

   do(reorderedCs);
}
```

Obviously this won't work. I could get around it by giving up and just making `do` a template over *any* type like this:

```
template<typename T>
void do(const vector<T>& cs) {
```

But it really only works with `C`'s and I'd like that to be encoded in the type system - and also it makes `do()` easier to understand if you don't have to go hunting around for places where it is used.

Is there any way to write `do()` so that it can generically take both `vector<C>` and `vector<C*>` (and for bonus points `vector<reference_wrapper<C>>`)?

Comment: If you have C++ 11, you can do following: 
void do(vector<C>&& cs),  this wil move your vector instead of copying int. But if you'd like to use it in the calling function, simply do it like void do(vector<C>& cs)

Comment: @VictorGubin - The answer section is down there. If I suspect correctly and you intend to post code in a comment, don't.

Comment: Can `C`'s be moved?  If so C++11 and above vectors support moving elements instead of copying them.

Comment: `type_traits`, `enable_if`, _et al._ can presumably help here.

Comment: `do` is an invalid function name... `do while`.

Answer (score 2):

Just write 2 template functions that applies a functor:

```
template<class T,typename Func>
void apply( const std::vector<T> &v, Func f )
{
    for( const auto &i : v ) f( i );
}

template<class T,typename Func>
void apply( const std::vector<T*> &v, Func f )
{
    for( auto i : v ) f( *i );
}
```

then pass a lambda:

```
std::vector<C> vc;
std::vector<C*> vp;
auto call = []( const C &c ) { c.do_whatever(); };
apply( vc, call );
apply( vp, call );
```

(note you cannot call your function `do` - it is a keyword in C++)

[live example](https://ideone.com/Skvqn3)

PS As you mentioned in comments your function `apply` is rather complex so you prefer to have only one copy of it, in this case create a helper:

```
template<class T>
const T &apply_helper( const T *t ) { return *t; }

template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_pointer<T>::value, const T &>::type 
apply_helper( const T &t )  { return t; }
```

then write your `apply` function only once:

```
template<class T,typename Func>
void apply( const std::vector<T> &v, Func f )
{
    for( const auto &i : v ) f( apply_helper( i ) );
}
```

[live example N2](https://ideone.com/FtaLXn)

Comment: My actual code is more complex than just looping over the vector and applying a function to it though, so I'll basically just be copying and pasting the entire function which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Then do not pass argument directly to `f` but have helper function, that passes reference directly and dereferences pointer.

Comment: Sorry I don't see how that prevents copying and pasting lots of the function, since it can't all be bundled neatly into an `f()` function that operates on each element independently.

Comment: See my updated answer and new example. Note you can use `apply_helper`  without functor ie directly like `apply_helper(elem).do_whatever()`

Comment: Ah ok, in that case you do need the `class T` template, and this was something I specifically wanted to avoid (see "I could get around it by giving up..." in the question).

Comment: "and this was something I specifically wanted to avoid" you either write generic code or write it for each type manually. And your reasoning why you want to avoid template is not clear.

Comment: It's not unclear: "it makes do() easier to understand if you don't have to go hunting around for places where it is used" (and there are other reasons, e.g. code completion). But I think you are right there is no way to do this without fully generic code. That was kind of the point of the question - I want something generic wrt "pointerness" but *not* generic wrt the specific class. I guess this is something C++ lacks. (Other languages like Java don't have this issue because *everything* is a pointer)

Comment: @Timmmm "I guess this is something C++ lacks." strange conclusion. Limit yourself to only using pointers and here you go - you problem is solved. Or you want to get flexibility and not to pay for that? No way, sorry.

Comment: "No way, sorry" - err yeah because C++ doesn't support it.

Comment: No, because there are no free lunches in this world. You do not have this issue in Java because it does not support objects by value, not vice versa

Comment: Come on, use your imagination! C++ could definitely support a templating type thing that *only* templates out the pointer-ness of a class. Not saying it's a good idea but I can't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible.

Comment: Just because you do not like or do not understand templates? No way.

Answer (score 1):

You might keep your `do` function generic, but specialize a getter for `T&` and `T*` that both return a `T&`:

```
namespace detail{
    template<class T>
    T& get(T& _in){
        return _in;
    }

    template<class T>
    T& get(T* _in){
        return *_in;
    }
} // namespace detail

template<class T>
void do_a_thing(const std::vector<T>& cs) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < cs.size(); ++i) {
      detail::get(cs[i]).do_whatever();
   }
}
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/s1od1VmcS4TTMtvC)

Either way you are going to need to specialize between pointers and references. I think that this pushes it to the smallest scope.

---

If you want to constrain `do_a_thing` to only accept `C` or `C*`, we can create a small trait to do this:

```
template <class T>
struct is_c : std::false_type{};

template <>
struct is_c<C>: std::true_type{};

template <>
struct is_c<C*>: std::true_type{};
```

And then modify `do_a_thing` with `std::enable_if`:

```
template<class T, std::enable_if_t<is_c<T>::value, int> = 0>
void do_a_thing(const std::vector<T>& cs) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < cs.size(); ++i) {
      detail::get(cs[i]).do_whatever();
   }
}
```

For bonus points, we'll write another specialization of `do_a_thing` that gives a nice compiler error for types that do not satisfy the constraint:

```
template<class T>
struct always_false : std::false_type{};

template<class T, std::enable_if_t<!is_c<T>::value, int> = 0>
void do_a_thing(const std::vector<T>& cs) {
   static_assert(always_false<T>::value, "do_a_thing only works for C and C*");
}
```

Now the following will fail:

```
struct Q{};
std::vector<Q> qs;
do_a_thing(qs); // compiler error
```

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZFih8nrOLNZ4Tqa4)

Comment: Yeah this is basically the solution I put in the question. :-/

Comment: @Timmmm: I think this is quite different. In the question, you had to specialize the entirely of your `do` function. If you look closely here, you are only specializing the accessor for the vector. You will have to handle references and pointers separately in any solution you do, I feel like this answer does it in the smallest scope possible.

Comment: Yeah I didn't put the full code but it is the solution I meant. `template<typename T> void do(const vector<T>& cs) {` is the same as `template<class T> void do_a_thing(const std::vector<T>& cs) {`.

Comment: @Timmmm: I meant for `do_a_thing` to represent your `do` function; this isn't a new function I'm advocating for, `do` is a reserved keyword in C++ so you have to name the function something else.

Comment: Yeah... I know...? Sorry I think we are probably agreeing with each other!

Comment: @Timmmm: I think you're right. I updated the post, is this any better?

Answer (score 1):

Write a function template that gets a *pair of iterators* (not a vector).

Then pass it either normal `vector<C>::iterator`s, or *adapted* `vector<C*>::iterator`s, e.g. `boost::transform_iterator` instances.

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

int& deref(int*& x) { return *x; }

template <class it>
void print(it from, it to)
{
    std::copy(from, to, std::ostream_iterator<typename it::value_type>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a {4,3,7,1};
    std::vector<int*> b {new int(2), new int(0), new int(11), new int(-3)};

    //    auto deref = [](int*& x) -> int& { return *x; };
    //    cannot use a lambda here because it's non-copyable
    //    and iterators must be copyable.

    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    std::sort(boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(b), &deref),
              boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(b), &deref));

    print(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    print(boost::make_transform_iterator(std::begin(b), &deref),
          boost::make_transform_iterator(std::end(b), &deref));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a possible solution could be to create a modified `vector` class that is generic with respect to pointerness, and can be implicitly converted to from a `vector<T>` or a `vector<T*>`. Like this:

```
template<typename T>
class VectorWrapper {
public:
    VectorWrapper(const vector<T>& v) : reference(&v) { }
    VectorWrapper(const vector<T*>& v) : pointer(&v) { }

    const T& at(int idx) const {
        if (reference)
           return (*reference)[idx];
        return *(*pointer)[idx];
    }

    // etc. for size() and so on. You could probably have
    // this class derive from std::vector and reimplement its
    // methods to switch between `reference` and `pointer`.

private:
    const vector<T>* reference = nullptr;
    const vector<T*>* pointer = nullptr;
};

void do_thing(VectorWrapper<C> wrapper) {
    wrapper.at(0).whatever();
}
```

Not tested, and I don't think I'll go this route to be honest but it's the best I could come up with.

Comment: At that point you might as well use a `variant` and a visitor pattern. Otherwise the class is hard to reason about.

Comment: You mean something like `void do_thing(variant<vector<C>, vector<C*>> wrapper) { ...`? Good point. I think using the visitor pattern would be extremely verbose but you could write a generic accessor for the variant.